# Please check the 'exp' claim when calling the BOX OAUTH2 /token with a JWT

Tags: oauth-2.0, box-api, jwt

here is the format of the exp value I'm inserting into the JWT, it's 50 secs greater than the current time: 1444727465.

However the JWT verification rejects the claim... any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK...with a little bit of looking at the API without assumptions I realised that the exp value had to be an int, not a string.

Problem solved

Comment: I've been getting the same error intermittently and I am using an int. After you made it an int, does it work all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Since token lifetime is 60seconds, the time between Box servers and your machine is very sensitive, Make sure that your computer time is synchronized.

Comment: This is what happened to me as well.  The clock on my computer was not set to be automatic.